# validation illegal characters going through with valid

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does my javascript form validation allow illegal characters through when valid characters are entered alongside them?

Here is my script

```
//Address Validation
var Address1 = document.forms ["tiptopform"]["Address1"].value;
var message="Please enter a valid Address" ;
var problem=false;
var patt1=new RegExp (/[A-Za-z0-9-]/);
var result = patt1.test(Address1);
if (result){
    message=message;
    problem=true
}
if (problem) {
    alert (message)
}
```

I have tried reversing the true and false variable but that as expected only reverses the problem.

Comment: I suggest you look at your regular expression, and what you exactly want it to match. I find software like kiki (https://code.google.com/p/kiki-re/) very useful with that :)

Comment: Hi Daan I have visited this site but cant find an input to enter the code.

Comment: do you know where I can find a good wig shop !!!

Comment: better try http://regexpal.com/

Comment: KiKi is a piece of software that you download, from the download page. If you want an online service to do the same, look elsewhere. Google (or duckduckgo) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing if you regular expression can be found within prvided address.

You want to match whoel adress and tets if it conatins only specific characters, use:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9-]*$/
```

that is from start to end any number of those characters

sidenote: /regexp/ is a waz to write dont regular expression, zou don't have to call new RegExp or you can provide this regualr expression as string then use

```
new RegExp ("^[A-Za-z0-9-]*$");
```